# Multi-language site with php for href links?

Tags: php, href, multilingual

I have a multi-language site but when I click on a href the links point to the default language instead of the language you actually are. How can I fix this?

I have three languages, spanish, english and french. This is the code I have in a head.php

```
  // Languages
$defaultLanguage = 'es';
$availableLanguages = array('es','en' ,'fr');

// Get language, check it and get translations
$txt = array();
if (isset($_REQUEST['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];

    if (in_array($lang, $availableLanguages)) {
        include('php/translations/' . $lang . '.php');
    } else {
        $lang = $defaultLanguage;
        include('php/translations/' . $defaultLanguage . '.php');
    }
} else {
    $lang = $defaultLanguage;
    include('php/translations/' . $defaultLanguage . '.php');
}

?>
```

and the nav with the links:

```
  <li><a <?=($pagina == 'page1') ? 'class="active"':''?> href="page1.php"><?=$txt['menu_1']?></a></li>
  <li><a <?=($pagina == 'page2') ? 'class="active"':''?> href="page2.php"><?=$txt['menu_2']?></a></li>
  <li><a <?=($pagina == 'page3') ? 'class="active"':''?> href="page3.php"><?=$txt['menu_3']?></a></li>
  <li><a <?=($pagina == 'page4') ? 'class="active"':''?> href="page4.php"><?=$txt['menu_4']?></a></li>
```

Comment: When someone changes the language, you could store it in a session. Then you can use the session on each page load instead when deciding what language to show. Another alternative would be to add it as a query parameter `?lang=xx` on each link. You could also do as most sites do, using the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) together with a router and use URL's like: `/es/page1`, `/en/page1` etc. Or you could use some framework with multi lingual support. Then you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: in the '?lang=xx' how do I set the variable of xx?

Comment: On each request, you will get the language in the query string, so you can just fetch it with `$lang = $_GET['lang'];`. Then you can verify the language and if it's a valid one, just use that to add it to the end of your URL's: `href="page1.php?lang=<?= $lang ?>"`. Just make sure you verify it first (since the users can change that to anything)